# QGIS include action (hyperlink) in composer output

Tags: qgis, print-composer, hyperlink

Is there a way to include the action "open url" in my map created in composer? I'm open to the final export being either a pdf or an image, but I'd like the end user to be able to click on different items within the map and it open the specified url (I've already set this up in the action menu in QGIS).

Comment: would a SVG export fine too?

Comment: @LaughU, that would probably be fine as well. I don't have much experience with SVG, but the map is vector layers only.